# Inconsistent/different results for simple tweepy (python twitter api) script each time I run it

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get tweets from a user from twitter via the API with tweepy but each time I run the script I get a different result (different amount of result, number is random but almost never 200).

```
tweetlist=[]
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='CryptoCobain', tweet_mode="extended", include_rts = False).items(200):

tweetlist.append(status.full_text)
```

I tried various variations of this code for example adding the limit_handler from the documentation as well as adding multiple ways to catch errors:

```
def limit_handled(cursor):
while True:
    try:
        yield cursor.next()
    except tweepy.RateLimitError:
        print("rate limit reached")
        time.sleep(15 * 60)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e.__class__.__name__))        
        break 

for status in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='CryptoCobain', tweet_mode="extended", include_rts = False).items(200)):
tweetlist.append(status.full_text)
```

The reason seems to be a StopIteration error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\1 projects\investing project\crypto\investment research\Investment Bot\code\twitter\twittermentions.py", line 20, in limit_handled
    yield cursor.next()
  File "C:\Users\Kol_Y\.conda\envs\crypto\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 243, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "C:\Users\Kol_Y\.conda\envs\crypto\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 158, in next
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
47
```

Does anybody have an idea why I always get different results and what to do about it?
I tried with Python 3.9 and also with Python 3.6, each time setting up a new conda env with nothing but tweepy

There is also a similar stackoverflow question but without answers: [Tweepy doesn't work when looking at @realDonaldTrump account (inconsistent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683779/tweepy-doesnt-work-when-looking-at-realdonaldtrump-account-inconsistent)

Any input is much appreciated